# Script no funciona aunque la logica esta bien

Tags: javascript

Lo que intento hacer es que el div se pinte de rojo al primer click y al segundo click se pinte de aqua pero no funciona. Para mi el script esta bien pero no se que pasa

```js
var div;
var coloreado = 0;;

function clickdiv() {
  div = document.getElementsByClassName("divcolor");
  div[0].addEventListener("click", darcolor, false);
}

function darcolor() {

  if (coloreado == 0) {
    div[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    coloreado = 1;
  }
  if (coloreado == 1) {
    div[0].style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    coloreado = 0;
  }

}

window.onload = clickdiv;
```

```css
.divcolor {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: aqua
}
```

```html
<div class="divcolor">

</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay un pequeño error de lógica, y es que primero se ejecuta la comparación de `coloreado` con 0, la cual es verdadera, pero en dicho resultado (tras ingresar al if) se pone en 1 la variable y por consiguiente es verdadera la siguiente condición y se ejecuta también el contenido del segundo if.

Un else if lo soluciona, aunque hay otras formas:

```js
var div;
var coloreado = 0;

function clickdiv() {
  div = document.getElementsByClassName("divcolor");
  div[0].addEventListener("click", darcolor, false);
}

function darcolor() {
  if (coloreado == 0) {
    div[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    coloreado = 1;
  } else if (coloreado == 1) {
    div[0].style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    coloreado = 0;
  }

}

window.onload = clickdiv;
```

```css
.divcolor {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: aqua
}
```

```html
<div class="divcolor">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el segundo if por un else

```
if (coloreado == 0) {
        div[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        coloreado = 1;
        console.log("Hola soy rojo");
    }
    else {
        div[0].style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
        coloreado = 0;
        console.log("Hola soy aqua");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos solo es en la lógica de la comparación, en algún momento debería pasar por una condición secundaria es decir un else:

```
  var div;
var coloreado = 0;;

function clickdiv() {
  div = document.getElementsByClassName("divcolor");
  div[0].addEventListener("click", darcolor, false);
}

function darcolor() {

  if (coloreado == 0) {
    div[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    coloreado = 1;
  }
  else{


    div[0].style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    coloreado = 0;
  }

}

window.onload = clickdiv;
```

De lo contraruio técnicamente nunca sale del primer if que obviamente si se cumple pero jamás existe el caso de pasar al else